# Laravel 5 - class does not exist

Tags: laravel

Имеется свой роут контроллер, который обрабатывает все гет запросы, и в зависимости от того, какой запрос пришел, направляет на тот или иной контроллер, с передачей параметров.

Есть контроллер *catalog*

Пытаюсь сделать короткие ссылки, то есть `/catalog/test.html`

В роутере обрабатывая данный запрос, я смотрю на наличие `.html`, и если оно имеется, то передаю дальше первым параметром `view`, а вторым - `test.html`

Первый параметр обрабатывается как экшн, на который необходимо отправить, то есть если юзер перешел на страницу `http://site/catalog/test.html`, то должен сработать экшн *view*. Но при этом у меня выкидывает ошибку

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\Catalog\Actions\ActionView does not exist

При чем, если перейти на `http://site/catalog/view/test.html` - то все работает.

Никак не могу понять что я делаю не так...

Comment: класс подключаю через App::make.
Если просто создавать экземпляр класса, то все работает....

Comment: Видимо роутеры не так настроены. Добавьте их в вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос